# Angular 15 CLI Bundling Issue - taking longer time

Tags: angular, typescript

[image: time]

Angular 15 CLI Bundling Issue - taking longer time
While I'm going `npm start/ng serve` it is taking very long time mostly 20 mins & for every change/save also. Please check attached package.json and suggest me solution for my issue.

Angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "wellstack-ui": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["moment", "lodash", "venn.js"],
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": ["node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "developer": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.developer.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "qa": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "staging": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "10mb",
                  "maximumError": "10mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "150kb",
                  "maximumError": "150kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "wellstack-ui:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.js",
            "port":6634
          },
          "configurations": {
            "developer": {
              "browserTarget": "wellstack-ui:build:developer"
            },
            
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "wellstack-ui:build:development"
              
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "wellstack-ui:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": ["zone.js", "zone.js/testing"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "codeCoverage": true,
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.html"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false,
    "schematicCollections": ["@angular-eslint/schematics"]
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.9",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^13.0.0",
    "@types/d3": "^7.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "d3": "^7.8.4",
    "export-from-json": "^1.7.2",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "primeicons": "^6.0.1",
    "primeng": "^15.4.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "venn.js": "^0.2.10",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "15.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.9",
    "@types/d3": "^7.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.194",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.44.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.44.0",
    "eslint": "^8.28.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "husky": "^8.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.1",
    "prettier-eslint": "^15.0.1",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: please add your angular.json here

Comment: updated please verify @Storytellerr

Comment: Check, whether caching is enabled. It can write with every changes huge files to the disk.

Comment: not enabled any caching